# What is the use of the package w3-recs

Tags: apt, package-management

What does the `w3-recs` package do?

Is it a set of documents?

Is this a compiled binary software package?

A local version of the current W3C in HTML and CSS form?

If I was new and came across it accidentally, it would seem like something I would want, then never be able to find or use simply because the only information that can be found on this package on the internet, anywhere; besides the aforementioned description, is that it recommends www-browser.

Answer (score 2):

This package includes the Recommendations produced by the [World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/) standardization body in HTML format.

To get information about an Ubuntu package, visit this site:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/

w3-recs package information:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/w3-recs

w3-recs files list:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/all/w3-recs/filelist

Comment: Thank you for the links @cmak.fr The most useful was the files list. Just for the sake of more information: it is the recommended documentation of the W3C located (installation location) at /usr/share/doc-base/. There is an index.html where the user is intended to open with their choice of browser and have a full offline website. There are a total of ~14,813 files.